# I have three "a" class's that change color when selected, but I need one to be default on load of page

Tags: javascript, selected

I'm working on this project and I need to add this functionality where we have three products listed.

they started out as div's but changed them to ahref class's to link the entire area.

The box has to change color when hovered - which I have done.
The box needs to change to another color when clicked on - which I have also done.

The one thing I can't figure out is how to make the 2nd box default as selected but then have the color turn off when another one is selected

This is the javascript I have for the page.

```
var highlightLink = function () {
    var active = null, colour = '#f6efa2';
    if (this.attachEvent) this.attachEvent('onunload', function () {
        active = null;
    });
    return function (element) {
        if ((active != element) && element.style) {
            if (active) active.style.backgroundColor = '';
            element.style.backgroundColor = colour;
            active = element;
        }
    };

}();
```

here is one of the boxs

```
<a class="productBox1" href="#" border="0" onclick="highlightLink(this);">
```

I'm thinking I need an onload function in the body tag but I don't know what code is needed and I also need it to become unselected when another box is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do all the links share a common class (and they are the only elements that have that class)? Is it an option to add IDs to the links? You need to be able to retrieve the link you want to highlight. You don't need to listen to the `load` event, you can put the code that selects the element at the bottom of the page, before the closing `<body>` tag. Then it is also assured that the DOM is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every link has it's own class anyway, use it as ID instead:

```
<a id="productBox1" href="#" border="0" onclick="highlightLink(this);">
```

Use classes for common properties. For identifying single elements, use IDs.

Then you can add this to the bottom of your page (above the closing `<body>` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    highlightLink(document.getElementById('productBox1'));
</script>
```

or set

```
window.onload = function() {
    highlightLink(document.getElementById('productBox1'));
}
```

in the `<head>`.

Comment: If it was possible to kiss you through a screen I would.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're making this more complicated than it really is.  Try this (I'm assuming all your a tags have class productBox1):

```
$('.productBox1').click(function() {
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

Then have a css class called highlighted which has `background-color: #f6efa2`.
You need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in order to make this work properly.

Comment: right now I created a CSS class for each productbox

so there's .productBox1, .productBox2, .productBox3 - granted they are all pretty much the same.  but I thought I would have to differentiate them to get some sort of script to identify the box I wanted highlighted

as you can tell I'm not a cracking programmer,

Comment: I cannot see the OP mentioning jQuery.

Comment: In fact, I mentioned you need jQuery in order to make it work.  I highly recommend learning how to use it, and as such I add it to any answer involving javascript.  Don't troll my answer so you can make yours look better please.